# Issue on Grails GORM domain classes with "soft" joins

Tags: grails, grails-orm

I have mapped two tables on `Domain` classes, say:

- `Parent` table that `hasMany` of the table `Child`.
- `Child` table that `belongsTo` a table `Parent`.

I want point out that there is no specific `foreign keys` explicitly declared on the database, rather it is declared on the `GORM`'s mapping. But here's the catch: There are special types of `Child` that are orphans- that is, doesn't have their `Parent` table counterparts. Everytime I access these orphans via a valid `Child.findById()`, an error shows:

> `Message: No row with the given identifier exists`

that is not present when accessing a non-orphan `Child`. I had marshalled these `Domain` tables already in such a way that everytime a `Child` is parsed as JSON, it will have a property called `parents` which is an array of `Parent` and the other way around. It is already working- except for these orphans' case.

How should I fixed this? Should I remove their `GORM` join, since they are not actually joint on the database side?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm assuming you have domain classes that look like this:

```
class Parent {
    static hasMany = [children: Child]
}

class Child {
    static belongsTo = [parent: Parent]
}
```

That's a [bi-directional one-to-many association](http://emmanuelrosa.com/articles/grails-domain-class-associations/). GORM expects the child table to contain a foreign key to the parent, and the child can only exist if it has a parent.

One way to allow orphan children is do to as you suggested: remove the gorm associations. Another way is to remove the *belongsTo* to create a uni-directional association. That way a child can exist without a parent.